# Exception handling: using @JsonProperty value to make error message

Tags: java, json, error-handling, spring

If the validation in `RestController` fails, I need to handle `MethodArgumentNotValidException` and provide an errorMessage, that contains
info about all rejected fields of passed object. If any rejected field has `@JsonProperty` annotation with non-empty value, then I need to replace field name with this value in errorMessage. What do you think about this implemenation:

Dto example:

```
public class Person {

    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("interests")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private List<String> hobbies;

    // getters, setters, etc.
}
```

Invalid JSON passed to some RestController endpoint in request body:

```
    {
      "name": "",
      "interests": null
    }
```

Exception handler:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ApiError> handleMethodArgumentNotValidException(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {

        String errorMessage = getRejectedJsonProperties(e).entrySet()
                .stream()
                .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + ": " + String.join(", ", entry.getValue()))
                .collect(joining("; "));

        return constructResponse(errorMessage, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    private Map<String, List<String>> getRejectedJsonProperties(MethodArgumentNotValidException e) {

        Map<String, List<String>> rejectedProps = e.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors().stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(FieldError::getField, 
                                mapping(DefaultMessageSourceResolvable::getDefaultMessage, toList())));

        Arrays.stream(e.getParameter().getParameterType().getDeclaredFields())
                .filter(f -> rejectedProps.containsKey(f.getName()))
                .filter(f -> f.isAnnotationPresent(JsonProperty.class) && !f.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value().isEmpty())
                .forEach(f -> rejectedProps.put(f.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class).value(), rejectedProps.remove(f.getName())));

        return rejectedProps;
    }

    // constructResponse method
}
```

At first in `getRejectedJsonProperties()` I collect in `Map` all rejected field names as keys and `List` of error messages as value (e.g. `{name=[must not be empty]; hobbies=[must not be null, must not be empty"]}`).

Then I take all declared fields of validated object and if field has `JsonPropery` annotation I replace this entry with new key in `rejectedProps` map.

As a result, the `errorMessage` in `handleMethodArgumentNotValidException()`:

```
name: must not be empty; interests: must not be null, must not be empty
```

If you need any clarifications, please let me know and thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community, is the code working as expected? We only review code that is working as expected. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Right now your question has three votes to close.

Comment: Yes, it works as expected, then it can be closed.

Comment: To anyone in the close vote queue, this question was just discussed in the [2nd Monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) and we don't see any reason why it should be closed. It does need an answer.